# Understanding const Qualifier Position in Template Parameter Deduction for Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, constants

I'm working on understanding how the const qualifier affects deduced types in C++ template functions, especially when pointers are involved. Consider the following template function:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
void foo(const T val) {
    if (std::is_pointer<T>::value) {
        std::cout << "foo() called for a pointer" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "foo() called for a value" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    int* y = &x;
    foo(y);
}
```

When I call foo(y), with y being a pointer to int, I noticed that T is deduced as `int*`, and the function parameter val becomes `int* const`. I would like to confirm my understanding:

Why does `const` apply to the pointer itself, not to the pointed type (i.e., `int* const` instead of `const int*`)?
Is there a rule in the C++ standard that defines how const is applied in such template type deductions?

Links to C++Insights : https://cppinsights.io/

the same is true for :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& val)
{
    if (std::is_pointer<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "foo() called for a pointer" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "foo() called for a value" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int*  y = &x;
    foo(y);
}
```

Comment: It's for the same reason why `typedef int *foo; const foo bar=nullptr;` you end up with an `int * const bar` getting defined, and not `const int *bar;`. That's how C++ works.

Comment: Wouldn't it be extremely confusing if `const T val` _didn't_ declare `val` to be const?

Comment: *"Why does `const` apply to the pointer itself, not to the pointed type"* -- In other words, why does `const` apply to the type itself, and not to something buried deep inside the type? Why do you end up with `const T` instead of breaking `T` up into component pieces and picking something inside to which to apply `const`?

Comment: How do you read `const T v`?  “v is a constant T”. Now replace “T” with “pointer” and convert it back to a declaration. What do you get?

Comment: If you want it to apply to something deeper, write it that way: `void foo(T const * ptr)` will be a pointer to a const T (whatever that is).

Comment: I would strongly suggest using "east-const" notation, i.e. put the const exactly to the right of the thing you want to make const. Then do the substitution with the template parameters and it should be much more obvious what's going on ,and where the const applies.